# "Class1" class has "Class2" object as a private data member. How can i refer to "Class1" object through "Class 2" function?

Tags: c++

**Class1.h:**

```
include "Class2.h"

class Class1
{
    public:
        Class1();

        int getNum();
        Class2 getClass2Object();//returns a Class2 object 

    protected:

    private:

        int num;
        Class2 class2Object;//Class2 object as a data member of Class1
};
```

**Class1.cpp:**

```
include "Class1.h"

Class1::Class1()
{
    num = 1;
}

int Class1::getNum(){return num;}
Class2 Class1::getClass2Object(){return class2Object;}
```

**Class2.h:**

> `accessNumThroughClass2()` function in which I need to refer to the `Class1` object that
>     has this `Class2` object as a data member

```
class Class2
{
    public:
        Class2();

        void accessNumThroughClass2();

    protected:

    private:
};
```

**Class2.cpp:**

> Here I want to refer to the `Class1` object that has the `Class2` object as a data member so that i 
>    can access the `num` data member in order to print its value. How can I do that?

```
Class2::Class2()
{
    //ctor
}

void Class2::accessNumThroughClass2(){
    //What do I do here?
}
```

**main.cpp:**

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Class1 class1Object();
    class1Object.getClass2Object().accessNumThroughClass2(); //Here make it print the value of num

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Short and only answer is: You can't. Not unless the `Class2` object have a freference to the `Class1` object.

Comment: There's no *portable* way of doing this. Which compiler are you using?

Comment: @Bathseba GNU GCC

Comment: Note that `Class2 Class1::getClass2Object(){return class2Object;}` returns a copy of the `Class2` object...

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude If I was to do that I would have to `#include "Class1.h" ` inside `Class2.h` file and I can't do that because I am already doing the opposite. Is there a way where 2 **.h** files can include each other?

Comment: Please do some research about *forward declarations*, which is the common way to solve circular dependencies. To declare a pointer or reference to a class, all you need is the forward declaration of the class, not the full class definition.

Comment: @AndreasKostas You can forward declare classes. Add `class Class1;` in `Class2.h` before the `Class2` definition.

Answer (score 1):

By doing a little research on **forward declarations** I can actually declare `Class1` inside `Class2.h` before `Class2` definition and then only use pointers to `Class1` objects. This solves my problem. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Create a member in Class2 that holds Class1 instance (call it for example parent). In Class2 constructor, recieve an instance of Class1 to initialize parent member.

In Class1 constructor, initialize class2Object with an instance of Class2 and pass this to Class2 constructor.

Something like this:

**Class2.h**

```
class Class2
{
    public:
        Class2();

        void accessNumThroughClass2();

    protected:

    private:
         Class1 parent;
};
```

**Class2.cpp**

```
Class2::Class2(Class1 parent)
{
    this.parent = parent;
}

void Class2::accessNumThroughClass2(){
    return parent;
}
```

**Class1.cpp**

```
include "Class1.h"

Class1::Class1()
{
    num = 1;
    class2Object = Class2(this);
}

int Class1::getNum(){return num;}
Class2 Class1::getClass2Object(){return class2Object;}
```

Comment: There's a couple of problems with this solution: `this` in the `Class1` constructor will be a totally different object from `parent` in the `Class2` object you create. Not to mention that `this` is a different type than `Class1` (which is a problem how you access `this` in the `Class2` constructor as well). The *principle* is sound though, even though the code isn't.